# How to use custom adpter with endless adapter

Tags: android, custom-lists, cwac-endless

I am trying to work with endless adapter  , i followed this example

http://droidista.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html

and

I have tried this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    static int LIST_SIZE;
     private int mLastOffset = 0;

     static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;


     private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

     String[] product = new String[]{"P1" , "P2" , "P3" , "P4" , "P5" ,"P6" ,
                "P7" , "P8" , "P9" , "P10" , "P11" ,"P12" ,
                "P13" , "P14" , "P15" , "P16" , "P17" ,"P18" ,
                "P19" , "P20" , "P21" , "P22" , "P23" ,"P24" ,
                "P1" , "P2" , "P3" , "P4" , "P5" ,"P6" ,
                "P7" , "P8" , "P9" , "P10" , "P11" ,"P12" ,
                "P13" , "P14" , "P15" , "P16" , "P17" ,"P18" ,
                "P19" , "P20" , "P21" , "P22" , "P23" ,"P24" ,
                "Val1" , "Val2" , "Val3" , "Val4" , "Val5" ,"Val6" ,
                "Val7" , "Val8" , "Val9" , "Val10" , "Val11" ,"Val12" ,
                "Val13" , "Val14" , "Val15" , "Val16" , "Val17" ,"Val18" ,
                "Val19" , "Val20" , "Val21" , "Val22" , "Val23" ,"Val24" ,
                "Val1" , "Val2" , "Val3" , "Val4" , "Val5" ,"Val6" ,
                "Val7" , "Val8" , "Val9" , "Val10" , "Val11" ,"Val12" ,
                "Val13" , "Val14" , "Val15" , "Val16" , "Val17" ,"Val18" ,
                "Val19" , "Val20" , "Val21" , "Val22" , "Val23" ,"Val24"};



     String[] shop_items = new String[]{"Val1" , "Val2" , "Val3" , "Val4" , "Val5" ,"Val6" ,
                "Val7" , "Val8" , "Val9" , "Val10" , "Val11" ,"Val12" ,
                "Val13" , "Val14" , "Val15" , "Val16" , "Val17" ,"Val18" ,
                "Val19" , "Val20" , "Val21" , "Val22" , "Val23" ,"Val24" ,
                "Val1" , "Val2" , "Val3" , "Val4" , "Val5" ,"Val6" ,
                "Val7" , "Val8" , "Val9" , "Val10" , "Val11" ,"Val12" ,
                "Val13" , "Val14" , "Val15" , "Val16" , "Val17" ,"Val18" ,
                "Val19" , "Val20" , "Val21" , "Val22" , "Val23" ,"Val24" ,
                "P1" , "P2" , "P3" , "P4" , "P5" ,"P6" ,
                "P7" , "P8" , "P9" , "P10" , "P11" ,"P12" ,
                "P13" , "P14" , "P15" , "P16" , "P17" ,"P18" ,
                "P19" , "P20" , "P21" , "P22" , "P23" ,"P24" ,
                "P1" , "P2" , "P3" , "P4" , "P5" ,"P6" ,
                "P7" , "P8" , "P9" , "P10" , "P11" ,"P12" ,
                "P13" , "P14" , "P15" , "P16" , "P17" ,"P18" ,
                "P19" , "P20" , "P21" , "P22" , "P23" ,"P24"};



         ArrayList<String> ProdcutList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
         ArrayList<String> ValList1 = new ArrayList<String>();




         ListView SimpleList ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        SimpleList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        init();
                //DisplayList();

         for (int i=0; i<product.length; i++){
               ValList1.add(product[i]);
              }


    }

    private void init() {
          LIST_SIZE = shop_items.length; 
          for (int i=0; i<=BATCH_SIZE; i++){
           ProdcutList1.add(shop_items[i]);  
//         ValList1.add(product[i]);
          }
          setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
          displayList(ProdcutList1);
         }

         private void setLastOffset(int i) {
          mLastOffset = i; 
         }

         private int getLastOffset(){
          return mLastOffset;
         }

         private void displayList(ArrayList<String> ProdcutList1) { 
          SimpleList.setAdapter(new DemoAdapter());
         }

         private class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

          public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
           super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
          } 

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           ViewHolder holder;  

           if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.set_aside_items, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.word = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.producttitle);
            holder.world = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
           } else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
           }

            holder.word.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)  + ". " + ProdcutList1.get(position));
           holder.world.setText(String.valueOf(position+1)  + ". " + ValList1.get(position));

           return convertView;
          }

          public class ViewHolder{
           public TextView word , world;       
          } 
         }

         class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {

          private RotateAnimation rotate=null;
          private View pendingView=null;
          ArrayList<String> tempList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> tempList2 = new ArrayList<String>();


          DemoAdapter() {
           super(new CustomArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ProdcutList1));

           rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
             0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
             0.5f);
           rotate.setDuration(600);
           rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
           rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
          }

          @Override
          protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
           View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

           View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
           child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
           child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           child.startAnimation(rotate);

           return(row);
          }

          @Override
          protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
           tempList1.clear();
           tempList2.clear();

           int lastOffset = getLastOffset();
           if(lastOffset < LIST_SIZE){
            int limit = lastOffset + BATCH_SIZE;
            for(int i=(lastOffset+1); (i<=limit && i<LIST_SIZE); i++){
             tempList1.add(shop_items[i]);
             tempList2.add(product[i]);


            }   
            setLastOffset(limit);

            if(limit<LIST_SIZE){
             return true;
            } else {
             return false;
            }
           } else  {
            return false;
           }
          }


          @Override
          protected void appendCachedData() {

           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapterNew1 = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getWrappedAdapter();


           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapterNew2 = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getWrappedAdapter();


           int listLen = tempList1.size();
           for(int i=0; i<listLen; i++){
            arrAdapterNew1.add(tempList1.get(i));

//          arrAdapterNew1.
            arrAdapterNew1.add(tempList2.get(i));

            arrAdapterNew1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            arrAdapterNew2.add(tempList2.get(i));

              displayList(tempList1);

           }
//         }
          }

          void startProgressAnimation() {
                if (pendingView!=null) {
                  pendingView.startAnimation(rotate);
                }
         }


         }
}
```

But this code works for only first ten values there after on scrolling it gives the following error

```
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 11
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.example.smaple_endlessadapter.MainActivity$CustomArrayAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:145)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.commonsware.cwac.adapter.AdapterWrapper.getView(AdapterWrapper.java:117)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter.getView(EndlessAdapter.java:261)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3087)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3032)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3357)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-02 15:24:54.031: E/AndroidRuntime(3001):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can make a custom list with endless adapter?

Comment: please if you tell the reason for downvote would be helpful, so I would be able to improve my question

Comment: but first 10 values are working fine

Comment: problem is here `for (int i=0; i<=BATCH_SIZE; i++){` use `i<BATCH_SIZE` instead of `i<=BATCH_SIZE` because array size is 10 and you are initializing i with o instead of 1

Comment: thanks i shall try and let you know

Comment: no it did not help the IndexOutOfBoundsException error value changed from 11 to 10

Comment: i mean change `i<=BATCH_SIZE` to `i<BATCH_SIZE` instead of changing elements in Array

Comment: i used this  for (int i=0; i<BATCH_SIZE; i++){
     ProdcutList1.add(shop_items[i]);  
     ValList1.add(product[i]);
    }

Comment: Please do not use `EndlessAdapter` here. Please just load all of the data, since *you already have all of the data*. `EndlessAdapter` is specifically for cases where it takes work to load all of the data, and you wish to do that work in batches as the user scrolls.

Comment: @AviKumarManku : what is line number 145 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: @CommonsWare i am trying to learn how can i implement this , so i put static values please can you suggest me how can i do this

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the line number 145 is                    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

Comment: @AviKumarManku : ok then check `position` value with `ProdcutList1` and `ValList1` ArrayList size before getting value from it bez logcat results clearly state that wrong indexed is passed for retrieving value. just try it as `if(position<ProdcutList1.size){get value here}else{assign default value}`

Comment: this code works fine if i use a simple list

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes the it works fine with this there is no crash the value of productlist1 starts from p12 and adds custom text in vallist1 on position value 10